# What's the reasoning behind this colon in Dart

Tags: dart

I'm checking out some dart code and looking at this:

```
  AppState.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : cartItems = (json['cartItems'] as List)
            .map((i) => new CartItem.fromJson(i as Map<String, dynamic>))
            .toList();
```

What's the reasoning behind the colon?
Why is this different from a regular assignment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find more info in the dart tour: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#classes

> If the superclass doesn’t have an unnamed, no-argument constructor, then you must manually call one of the constructors in the superclass. Specify the superclass constructor after a colon (:), just before the constructor body (if any).
>
> Besides invoking a superclass constructor, you can also initialize instance variables before the constructor body runs. Separate initializers with commas.

```
// Initializer list sets instance variables before
// the constructor body runs.
Point.fromJson(Map<String, num> json)
    : x = json['x'],
      y = json['y'] {
  print('In Point.fromJson(): ($x, $y)');
}
```

> During development, you can validate inputs by using assert in the initializer list.

```
Point.withAssert(this.x, this.y) : assert(x >= 0) {
  print('In Point.withAssert(): ($x, $y)');
}
```

You can also use them to initialize the final variables:

```
class Point {
  final num x;
  final num y;
  final num distanceFromOrigin;

  Point(x, y)
      : x = x,
        y = y,
        distanceFromOrigin = sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}
```

Comment: Awkward syntax coming from Java, but works for me. Thanks.